# Syntaxhighlighting with Redcarpet and Rouge does not work in Rails 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, redcarpet, rouge

Does anyone have experience with the Redcarpet and Rouge gems for Rails?
I'm trying to use the gems for syntaxhighlighting in my blogapplication. I based my implementation on this blogpost:

http://www.brettdemetris.com/posts/4

These are the steps I took:

I implemented the gems (Redcarpet, Rouge)

my Applicationhelper file looks like this:

```
app/helpers/application_helper.rb

module ApplicationHelper

require 'rouge'
require 'rouge/plugins/redcarpet'

class HTML < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  include Rouge::Plugins::Redcarpet

  def block_code(code, language)
    Rouge.highlight(code, language || 'text', 'html')
  end
end

def markdown(text)
    options = {
      filter_html:     true,
      hard_wrap:       true,
      link_attributes: { rel: 'nofollow', target: "_blank" },
      space_after_headers: true,
      fenced_code_blocks: true
    }

    extensions = {
      autolink:           true,
      highlight:          true,
      superscript:        true,
      disable_indented_code_blocks: true
    }

    renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(options)
    markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions)

    markdown.render(text).html_safe
  end
end
```

I have a stylesheet for Rouge:
    app/assets/stylesheets/rouge.css.erb

```
<%= Rouge::Themes::Github.render(:scope => '.highlight, code') %>

.highlight {
  background-color: #f5f7f9;
  padding: 1em;
}

.highlight .err {
    color: #a61717;
    background-color: #f5f7f9;
}
```

Apperently the conversion to markdown works, but not the syntaxhighlighting with Rouge:

for example when I use this code in my blogpost:

````
```ruby
e =  "some ruby code"
e.puts
```
````

the code is not highlighted.

the output of the above code snippet is this:

```
<pre><code class="ruby">e = &quot;some variable&quot;
e.puts
</code></pre>
```

Am I missing something?

my code repository is here:

https://github.com/acandael/personalsite/tree/markdown

any advice is highly appreciated

greetings,

Anthony

Comment: What is the output produced by your `markdown` method/helper for your ruby example? Also, if I'm not mistaken, `fenced_code_blocks: true` is [an extension](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet#user-content-and-its-like-really-simple-to-use) (should be in your `extensions` hash, not `options`). (same for `space_after_headers`)

Comment: thanks julp for the advice, the output of the code is wrapped in pre tags

Comment: adding to my previous reply to julp, the output is also wrapped in code tags with a class=ruby

Comment: You have to replace `renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(options)` by `renderer = HTML.new(options)`

Comment: I replaced the line you suggested, now the output is: <pre class="highlight"><code><span class="n">e</span> <span class="o">=</span> <span class="s2">"some variable"</span>
<span class="n">e</span><span class="p">.</span><span class="nf">puts</span>
</code></pre> But I don't see any styles applied. I wonder if the .highlight class in app/assets/stylesheets/rouge.css.erb is picked up

Comment: As is in your page or when viewing its source? For the first, rails is probably escaping the result "string". For the second, check in your browser if you load an asset/stylesheet which corresponds to your app/assets/stylesheets/rouge.css.erb.

Comment: hi julp, good news, the syntaxhighligting is working. I fixed the escaping problem by using the raw() method. I fixed the css problem by requiring rouge in my app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss manifest file. Thanks a lot for your help, couldn't have done this without you!

Answer (score 2):

For people interested, this is the working code in my applicationhelper:

```
app/helpers/application_helper.rb

module ApplicationHelper

require 'redcarpet'
require 'rouge'
require 'rouge/plugins/redcarpet'

class HTML < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
  include Rouge::Plugins::Redcarpet

  def block_code(code, language)
    Rouge.highlight(code, language || 'text', 'html')
  end
end

def markdown(text)
    options = {
      filter_html:     true,
      hard_wrap:       true,
      link_attributes: { rel: 'nofollow', target: "_blank" }
    }

    extensions = {
      autolink:           true,
      highlight:          true,
      superscript:        true,
      disable_indented_code_blocks: true,
      space_after_headers: true,
      fenced_code_blocks: true
    }

    #renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(options)
    renderer = HTML.new(options)
    markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions)

    markdown.render(text).html_safe
  end
end
```

this is how I implemented it in the view:

```
app/views/articles/show.html.erb

<%= raw(markdown(@article.body)) %>
```

The markdown and syntaxhighlighting is working now.